# "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key" upgrading web form site from Framework 2 to 4.5

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2013

I have an old web forms app I am helping out with for a bit (**targeting framework 2.0**).  I wanted to see what would break if I targeted the 4.0 framework.  Most everything is working except when some of the forms are trying to reference member variables...

The following error is getting thrown.

> ```
> ArgumentNullException
> "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key"
> ```

```
input id="somefield" type="hidden" value="<%=membervariable%>" />
```

If I switched the target framework back to anything prior to 4 all is well.  Anything 4 and above raises the error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I am not sure but I feel this has something to do with ClientID.

Comment: I tried this to rule out anything with the member variables... in the form being generated I added <%="buildnumber"%>... just add some text... error breaks on this too.

Comment: what exactly is buildnumber ? did you try <%="buildnumber.ClientID"%> ?

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace?

Comment: It would really help if you could post your markup (at least as far as the input control) and code. @Karthik - buildnumber is a variable he declared in the form to test his hypothesis.